# TBXML Issue when parsing textForElement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ipad

I have a big problem using `TBXML`.

When I use:

```
+ (NSString*) textForElement:(TBXMLElement*)aXMLElement {
    if (nil == aXMLElement->text) return @"";
    return [NSString stringWithCString:&aXMLElement->text[0] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

to parse this `XML`

```
[...]
<step id=123>this string is not parsed
  <draw_at x="1964"/>
  <partials>
    <partial sd="23">
      <line>ANOTHER TEXT 1</line>
      <line>ANOTHER TEXT 2</line>
    </partial>
  </partials>
</step>
[...]
```

i get an **EMPTY** string.

*I suppose that is because STEP tag has more than one text,*

> indeed if I use same function to get
>   another STEP *without PARTIALS tag*,
>   the string is correct, not empty!

I get step in this way:

```
NSstring *_step = [TBXML textForElement:step];
```

Any idea to fix this issue?

thanks.

**EDIT**: this XML is valid. It's used by years. Is only a part copied from the original that is mooore long to paste here.

**EDIT 2**: i write by hand this snippet, probably omitting quotes or something else, but xml is valid.

Comment: In valid XML, every attribute value must be quoted.

Comment: @Bavarious my problem is text parsing, not the validity of the XML. That is valid when come out from server!

Comment: Its Parser issue.. they havent handled it i believe.Its better you put that string in one more tag.or ul have to go through their logic.

Comment: i cannot change this xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporary patched** using another parser for the line empty.
I'm using `PerformXMLXPathQuery()` from `XPathQuery.h/.m`

It works!

> ...and the **XML is correct and
>   validate with W3C** with **NO ERRORS** !

Report from *validator.w3.org*:

> This document was successfully checked
>   as well-formed XML!
>   Result: Passed, 1 warning(s)

If there is a better solution instead this patch, i change correct answer with the correct reply.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That XML is not valid XML so you will have issues with it. The same thing applies to libxml2 as well (I know as I had the same issue).

Comment: this XML is valid. It's used by years. Is only a part copied from the original that is mooore long to paste here.

Comment: It may be used for years but its not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear your problem with simple example, that i got from [forum](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/forum/) of TBXML

If you want to parse XML something like,

```
<xml> 
<alert id="b19260fa7f00000100258097dcd87ab7">
    <title>MU-Lancaster Now Open</title>
    <startdate>1304353800</startdate>
    <enddate>1304362800</enddate>
    <type>Emergency</type>
    <message>
        <p>MU-Lancaster, at 42 N. Prince St., in Lancaster, is now open.&#160; It had been closed this morning due to the evacuation of downtown Lancaster.</p>
    </message>
</alert>
```

Than you need to write code for parsing is as follow,

```
- (void)parseMuAlertXML{
TBXML *tbxml;
TBXMLElement *rootXMLElement;
TBXMLElement *node_alert;
TBXMLElement *node_message;
TBXMLElement *node_traverse;

time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.millersville.edu/alert/alert.xml"];

tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:url];
```

rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
    if(rootXMLElement)
    {
        node_alert = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"alert" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

```
    if(node_alert)
    {
        node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"startdate" parentElement:node_alert];
        NSInteger startString =  [[TBXML textForElement:node_traverse] intValue];
        time_t startTime = startString;

        node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"enddate" parentElement:node_alert];
        NSInteger endString =  [[TBXML textForElement:node_traverse] intValue];
        time_t endTime = endString;

        node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"type" parentElement:node_alert];
        alertType = [[TBXML textForElement:node_traverse] retain];

        node_message = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"message" parentElement:node_alert];

        if(node_message)
        {
            node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"p" parentElement:node_message];
            alertMessage = [TBXML textForElement:node_traverse];
            alertMessage = [alertMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#160;" withString:@" "];
        }

        if((unixTime >= startTime) && (unixTime <= endTime))
        {
            [alertButton setHidden:NO];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
        } else {
            [alertButton setHidden:YES];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
        }
    }
}
```

}

also your xml is not valid xml,
I think your xml would be,

```
<step id="123"> this string is not parsed<draw_at x="1964"/><partials><partial sd="23"><line>ANOTHER TEXT 1</line><line>ANOTHER TEXT</line></partial></partials></step>
```

Comment: @Simon your starting tag is <partialsd> and ending tag is <partials>, how it will be valid???

Comment: And if your xml was similar with a difference in <alert id="b192">TEXT<title>[...] how do you get TEXT?

Comment: I think.. There would be <step id="123"> instead of <step id=123> in XML

Comment: Ok, but it's not important! I need to get "this string is not parsed" not a correction for a valid XML (that is valid, but not this)!